# Is Iterable object in for statement checked(recalculated) everytime it runs?

Tags: python

While I'm solving problems in python3, I wrote a simple code like this,

```py
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement

word, n = input().split()
word, n = sorted(word), int(n)

for c in combinations_with_replacement(word, n):
    print(''.join(c))
```

and after that, I found out that others did like this,

```py
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement

s, k = input().split()

for c in combinations_with_replacement(sorted(s), int(k)):
    print("".join(c))
```

Now I'm curious about, "Does sorted() function runs one time? or more? (in `for c in combinations_with_replacement(sorted(s), int(k)):`)."
So, I wrote some code to test it.

```py
test = [1, 2, 3]

for t in test:
    print(t)
    test.append('hi')
```

and it continuously prints 'hi'

Is iterable object in for statement checked(recalculated) every time it runs? or it checked only when the iterable object changes?
And, in `for c in combinations_with_replacement(sorted(s), int(k)):`, Does sorted() function run only one time or run more?

Comment: A really easy way to check is to use this instead: `def sorted2(xs): print('Run once!'); return sorted(xs)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
combinations_with_replacement(sorted(s), int(k))
```

This is a function that takes a list and a number. You sort the list before passing it in.

`combinations_with_replacement` takes this information and returns an iterator.

Your

```
for c in combinations_with_replacement ...
```

loop doesn't ever see the list you pass in, only the iterator returned by `combinations_with_replacement`.

In short, no.